# Exposing function of a React component

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to expose a function of a React component?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   someFunction() {

      // I'd like to expose this function
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>Hello World</div>
      );
   }
}
```

In the above example, I'd like to expose `someFunction()` so that I can call it from the parent component.

In other words, I'm trying to call a function of a sub-component from the parent component.

Two questions:

1. Can I do this? If so, how?
2. This may be a more important question: Should I be doing this? I'm always mindful that something I may need now may be exposing an architectural flaw. So, I want to know if I should even be calling a sub-component's function from the parent component.

Comment: Can you give some insight into the specific reason you want to call the child component?

Comment: Sure. I created a `datePicker` component which pops open when clicked so that the user can select a date from the calendar. The modal open/close function is the function I want to expose. Up to this point, my usage scenarios didn't require me to expose this function. It was self contained. The current scenario requires me to either expose this function or create a small handler function in the parent component so that I can wire opening the `datePicker` modal. The latter approach will create some code repetition -- though not much code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is *possible* to call a function on a child component, I don't think it would be idiomatic.

If you want to change the way a component renders, you should alter its props and trigger a re-render.

Keeping the interface for a component exclusively through the props helps to better encapsulate the inner workings of the component.

For your specific example, I would rather have a `visible` toggle that you alter and let the `datePicker` component decide for itself what it wants to do with that property value.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I do this?

Yes, We can achieve that by using [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), assign ref to MyComponent when rendering inside parent component then use that ref to call the function.

> How?

Check this snippet:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component { 

   _callChildComponent(){
      this.child.someFunction();
   }

   render() {
      return(
          <div>
            <div onClick={() => this._callChildComponent()}>Call</div>
            <MyComponent ref={el => this.child = el}/>
          </div>
      );
   }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   someFunction() {
      console.log('hello');
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>Hello World</div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

But i will suggest you to pass a function from parent component to child component and use that function to pass data or for any other purpose instead of using ref.

Comment: Great answer, what happens to `child.someFunction` after the child was unmounted?

Comment: @webdeb if that component is getting rendered conditionally, then we simply need to put a check whether that exist or not before calling the child component function :)

Comment: can't we hook into `this.child.componentWillUnmount` ?